# CallKit add multiple IdentificationEntry with same phone number

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I would like to add multiple IdentificationEntry with same phone number and display them on phone. In my use case, multiple persons have the same phone number like boss and her assistent and I would like to identify these numbers. Currently the first entry would be identified.

Is it possible to add multiple IdentificationEntries with same phone number in Callkit? Is there an other solution to solve the problem?

```swift
var allPersons = [SimpleCallKitPerson]()
allPersons.append(SimpleCallKitPerson(name: "Bart Simpson", phone: 491705770140))
allPersons.append(SimpleCallKitPerson(name: "Homer Simpson", phone: 491705770140))
allPersons.append(SimpleCallKitPerson(name: "Maggi Simpson", phone: 491729182155))
allPersons.append(SimpleCallKitPerson(name: "Marge Simpson", phone: 491729182155))

allPersons.forEach { person in
  if let name = person.value(forKey: "name" ) as? String ,
     let phoneNumber = person.value(forKey: "phoneNumber") as? Int64 {
       callKitContext.addIdentificationEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber, label: name)
       callKitContext.completeRequest(completionHandler: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: do you get an error when you try it?

Comment: No i get now error. The entries would be added, but I only see one name if person called me.